# Change complicated strings in R with qsub or R-strings

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyverse, qsub

I have a column of a data frame that has thousands complicate sample names like this

```
sample- c("16_3_S16_R1_001", "16_3_S16_R2_001", "2_3_S2_R1_001","2_3_S2_R2_001")
```

I am trying with no success to change the sample names to achieve the following sample names
16.3R1, 16.3R2, 2.3R1,2.3R2

I am thinking of solving the problem with qsub or stringsR.
Any suggestion? I have tried qsub but not retrieving the desirable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sub` to extract the parts :

```
sample <- c("16_3_S16_R1_001","16_3_S16_R2_001","2_3_S2_R1_001","2_3_S2_R2_001")
sub('(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*(R\\d+).*', '\\1.\\2\\3', sample)
#[1] "16.3R1" "16.3R2" "2.3R1"  "2.3R2"
```

`\\d+` refers to one or more digits. The values captured between `()` are called as capture groups. So here we are capturing one or more digits(1), followed by underscore and by another digit (2) and finally "R" with a digit (3). The values which are captured are referred using back reference so `\\1` is the first value, `\\2` as second value and so on.

Comment: To replace the column in your data frame, you can use df %>% transmute(sample = sub(...)) inserting Ronak's solution

Comment: the \\d+ refers to one string right? what does the  \\1.\\2\\3 mean? sorry for asking? could you explain it further to me?

Comment: I added some explanation of the code @LDT

Answer (score 3):

If you split the string sample into substrings according to the pattern "_", you need only the 1st, 2n and 4th parts:

```
sample <- c("16_3_S16_R1_001", 
            "16_3_S16_R2_001",
            "2_3_S2_R1_001",
            "2_3_S2_R2_001")

x <- strsplit(sample, "_")

sapply(x, function(y) paste0(y[1], ".", y[2], y[4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could do it.

It helps to create a data frame with a header column, so it's what I did below, and I called the column "cats"

```
trial <- data.frame( "cats" = character(0))
x <- c("16_3_S16_R1_001", "16_3_S16_R2_001", "2_3_S2_R1_001","2_3_S2_R2_001")
df <- data.frame("cats" = x)
```

The data needs to be in the right structure, in our case, as.factor()

```
df$cats <- as.factor(df$cats)
levels(df$cats)[levels(df$cats)=="16_3_S16_R1_001"] <- "16.3R1"
levels(df$cats)[levels(df$cats)=="16_3_S16_R2_001"] <- "16.3R2"
levels(df$cats)[levels(df$cats)=="2_3_S2_R1_001"] <- "2.3R1"
levels(df$cats)[levels(df$cats)=="2_3_S2_R2_001"] <- "2.3R2"
```

And voilà

Comment: thank you Andy :) for your time. I have thousands of file and I was thinking more a qsub option. I need to make my question more clear.

Comment: O I see.  I think you will need to write a loop to go over it and do this for you.  Unfortunately, I am not the best with writing loops.

Comment: Unfortunately, a loop is not the answer since the issue is that this solution hardcodes "16.3R1", "16.3R2", etc., this solution would require hardcoding for potentially 1000s of unique levels. please see the other solutions that are more generalizable!